# ¿Cómo volver a validar los datos de una variable que me devuelve valor booleano?

Tags: php, array, variables

Realmente no sé si estoy mal al querer hacer y/o esta mal formulada la pregunta y si es así por favor háganmelo saber.

Lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente con el siguiente código:

```
$esigual4 = count(array_unique($valores4))===1;
```

Esto me devuelve un valor `boleano` *(TRUE)*, ya que busco en el `array` que todos los valores sean iguales dentro de un `array`, y si me devuelve un `TRUE`, meto la variable la igualo a una condición

```
if (uno==tres){
   alert("ambos son true");
}
else
 {#código};
```

Donde la `var` uno es igual a `true`,si esto se cumple no ejecuta el código, pero en mi caso tengo datos donde todo mi `array` es igual en todos los datos que si quiero mostrar:

Sin son guiones todos los valores del `array` no se ejecuta el código, pero el problema me surge que en ocasiones todos los valores del `array` son del mismo valor CON, el cual si necesito mostrar si no se cumple el que ambas variables sean iguales. 
En resumen como puedo diferenciar si el valor del `array` todos son guiones o si todos son otra palabra? existe alguna función de array ya intente con la siguiente pero me marca error:

```
$esigual = count(in_array('-',(array_unique($valores))))===1;
```

No tengo mucho tiempo en esto y realmente disculpen si ya son muchas preguntas y no me sé explicar correctamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A la validación anterior, donde se verificaba que `count(array_unique($valores)) === 1` para saber si todos son iguales, se podría añadir otra condición empleando la función [end](http://php.net/manual/es/function.end.php) donde verificamos que el ultimo elemento del `array` sea el carácter especifico.

```
$valores = array('0' => '-' , '1'=> '-' , '2' =>'-');
$esigual = count(array_unique($valores)) === 1 && end($valores) === '-';
var_dump($esigual); //true
```

> [Referencia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10560669/6502043)

Adaptando al intento de su código es decir con [in_array](http://php.net/manual/es/function.in-array.php) sería

```
$valores = array('0' => '-' , '1'=> '-' , '2' =>'-');
$esigual = count(array_unique($valores)) === 1 && in_array('-',$valores);
var_dump($esigual);
```

Comment: Excelente muchísimas gracias, eso es lo que necesitaba gracias nuevamente por tu ayuda!

Comment: @Fernando me alegro poder ayudar. Además recuerde que puede plantear las preguntas que sean necesarias y le ayudaremos con mucho gusto.